# Every vector field on $S^1$ is i-related to some vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$, i is the inclusion map

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

This question is from my quiz in Smooth manifolds and I am struck on this.

> Question :  Let $i: S^1 \to {\mathbb{R}}^2 $ be the usual inclusion map. Prove that every vector field on $S^1$  is i-related to some vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let f be a smooth function from M and N where $X\in \mathfrak X(M)$ and $Y\in \mathfrak X(N)$. Then X and Y are f-related if $df_p (X_p)= Y_{f(p)}$.

For vector fields on Manifolds consider the definition here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field

Definitions are clear to me but I am not able to understand how to use them in this question maybe because so less examples have been solved in the class.

Can you give me a few hints? I would like to fully prove it by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the idea would be to extend any given vector field $X$ which is tangent to $S^1$ to a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I would try to "extend by zero" away from the immersed unit circumference, possibly using an open covering and a subordinate partition of unity, if you are familiar with this technique.

Comment: Hint: The extension to $\Bbb R^2$ will have at least one point that is $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am sorry but I am not able to understand the hint. Do you mind writing a detailed answer? Thanks!

Comment: The hint was intended to address one possible way you might be having trouble figuring out how to smear the vector field on $S^1$ (considered as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$) to all of $\Bbb R^2$. Probably that guess about your difficulties on my part was wrong. For every $x \in \Bbb R^2$ except $0$, there are unique $r > 0$ and $e \in S^1$  such that $x = re$. Can think how to use that $r$ to define a vector at $x$ corresponding to the vector at $e$?